# Uncaught Object Error when adding route provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am new to angular js and was trying to create a webpage with route provider. The angular script works fine without the declaration of the route provider function. But when I add it it gives an error "Uncaught Object in the angular.min.js file" I have three html pages. The index.html page has all the scripts and a div with `ng-view`, view1.html and view2.html are the main files with the html content. I am new to angular js and just for the demo purpose I am writing the angular script within the html. Kindly help me out.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html data-ng-app="demoApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>

         <script src="angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
            <!-- Placeholder for views -->
            <div data-ng-view=""></div>
        </div>

        <script>
            var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

            demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
              $routeProvider
                .when('/',
                  {
                    controller: 'SimpleController', 
                    templateUrl: 'Partials/view1.html'
                  })
                .when('/view2',
                  {
                    controller: 'SimpleController', 
                    templateUrl: 'Partials/view2.html'
                  })
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
            });

            demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
              $scope.customers=[
                {name:'paresh', city: 'bangalore'},
                {name:'alpha', city: 'sanfrancisco'},
                {name:'roger', city: 'boulder'}
              ];

              $scope.addCustomer = function(){
                $scope.customers.push(
                  {
                    name  : $scope.newCustomer.name,
                    city: $scope.newCustomer.city
                  });
              };
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

view1.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>View 1</h2>
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name" />
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: filter.name | orderBy: 'city'">{{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city}}</li>
    </ul>

    <br>
    customer name<br>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.name"/>
    customer city<br>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.city"/>
    <br>
    <button data-ng-click="addCustomer()">Add customer</button>
    <a href="#/view2">view 2</a>
</div>
```

view2.html

```
<div>
    <h2>View 2</h2>
    City:<br>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.city" />
    <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: filter.city | orderBy: 'city'">{{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Please help me fix this. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the script

```
 <script src="angular-route.js">
```

Then inject the dependency into your module:

```
  var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['$routeProvider']);
  demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider
            .when('/',
              {
                controller: 'SimpleController', 
                templateUrl: 'Partials/view1.html'
              })
            .when('/view2',
              {
                controller: 'SimpleController', 
                templateUrl: 'Partials/view2.html'
              })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the ng-route dependency

Add this to your script tags

```
<script src="angular-route.js">
```

Then inject the dependency into your module

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

Hope this helps.